# How to redirect recaptcha with python requests to user that can solve it manually

Tags: python, python-requests, recaptcha, captcha

I'm trying to make a Bot, that can purchase Items from Supreme.
I'm almost finished, the only thing that stands in my way is the recaptcha, that you have to solve, to be able to checkout an Item on Supreme. I know its possible to redirect the captcha to a user, but can I do that with python requests and if so, how can I do this? Furthermore if I'm able to do so, how do i get the Captcha-Token that I need to make the Checkout-request? If somebody knows something about that, please please leave me a comment :)

Comment: There are a number of captcha-solving services that dispatch your request to a small army of human slaves, who solve them and send back the answer.  They are designed to be called with web requests.  I think it's unethical, so you'll have to Google for them.

Comment: When you say "a user", do you mean you / the person using the bot?

Comment: i heard of these kind of people, that solve the captchas, but like CrazyChucky already mentioned, i want the person that uses the bot, to solve the captchas